# Payment Gateways with the best API?

Tags: api, payment-gateway

Our company will soon need to integrate a payment gateway with our PHP web application for our users to be able to pay a "conference registration fee" using a credit card. Before defaulting to using Authorize.net, I want to find out from other developers which payment gateways you have used, and can recommend, that has an easy to use/integrate API.

FYI: Our company is in the U.S.A.

Comment: You should specify your country - there is many gateways which have no global range - ie. there is payline.com, quite good and nice to integrate (comes with ready to use SOAP library), but it's french and I don't think that is accessible yet in US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came across a company called [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). They are a developer focused payment processing company. They handle the payment gateway stuff so you don't have to. They also have extensive documentation and easy to use APIs.

Update: Another company similar to Stripe is [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com). Their product offering (and pricing model) is very similar.

Comment: I had heard of these guys before when they where US only. Good to see they now support UK :)

Answer (score 2):

Authorize.net is pretty much the standard for real merchant accounts. Most other providers even have an authorize.net emulation mode. The API is fairly standard - there isn't much room for creativity here.

I've worked with Amazon SimplePay which was relatively painless as well. Google Checkout is also fairly flexible. Neither of these is a real merchant account system of course.

Comment: +1 Authnet's API is about as easy and straight forward as it gets.

Comment: How does Paypal Website Payment Pro compare? We implemented a payment procedure using Website Payments Pro. It was quite straight forward. Paypal is not happy with our business model and thus we are looking for some one else.

Comment: @Ryan atconway just posted an answer which refers to PayPal's PayFlow Payment Gateway. I'm assuming PayPal Website Payment Pro is a different service, so you might want to check out this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I work for IP Commerce, we have payment APIs that you can use to connect to multiple service providers (Chase Paymentech, Vantiv, First Data, etc.). You can checkout some of our sample code on GitHub: https://github.com/ipcommerce

The real benefit of using us would be if you want to do payment acceptance for a multi-channel type of thing, like point-of-sale and ecommerce, as we can easily link online-to-onsite transactions-- e.g. buy a 'daily deal' on your smartphone and redeem it at the point-of-sale using the credit card you bought the deal with or a QR Code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend PayPal's [PayFlow Payment Gateway](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_payflow/). One thing to note - it is a 'PayPal' service but does not require any use of PayPal as payment by the consumer. When I had used it in the past, I had built my own 'credit card' payment page accepting the different major credit cards but didn't even use PayPal as one of the accepted types.

The nice thing was you package up all the information, send it off to the gateway API via HTTPS, and get essentially a response including the charge/decline information from the bank.

There is some setup that has to be done on the backend after deciding on a payment gateway for where the money goes and which payment types you can accept. There are also decision to be made around fraud protection filter levels, and PCI security questions if you so much as store any of the charge data.

There are other payment gateway APIs but I liked PayPal because of their developer focus on the products. That had an entire forum (it's on SO now), documentation, developers site, and multiple programming examples.